# .htaccess authentication 500 error

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection, internal-server-error

I get a 500 error with the below in my .htacess file I cannot figure out why.
I checked the path with `<?php echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]; ?>` -- it's /home/tedctcou/public_html/filename

Can anyone see a reason why that doesn't work? I hreally need help here... Many thanks!

```
AuthUserFile /home/tedctcou/public_html/.pswrd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Information for committee and board members. Please enter your login details to access this information."

<Files "staff.php">
    Require valid-user
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all

    Allow from 216.70.112.113
    Satisfy Any
</Files>
```

Comment: Check your Apache error.log for the reason of this error

Comment: Don't know immediately how to do check error.log. But I have some new info: When I delete <Files "staff.php"> and  </Files>, then the thing works. Of course, then the whole site is protected, but I only want to protect the one page.

Comment: Security

Make sure that the `AuthUserFile{ is stored outside the document tree of the web-server. Do not put it in the directory that it protects. Otherwise, clients may be able to download the `AuthUserFile`.

Comment: Do you mean I should not store it in the public_html folder? So, it should be /home/tedctcou/.pswrd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this :

```
<FilesMatch "staff.php">
        Require valid-user
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        AuthUserFile /home/tedctcou/.pswrd
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Information for committee and board members. Please enter your login details to access this information."
        Allow from 216.70.112.113
        Satisfy Any
    </FilesMatch>
```

Move your .pswrd !!